# How accurate is the O.J. Simpson trial series?

Tags: analysis, american-crime-story

Several months ago I watched *[The People v. O. J. Simpson: American Crime Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2788432/)*, and from what I can remember, most of the events in the series seemed accurate to what actually happened, but I'm definitely no expert on the subject..

**Are there any aspects of this show that just aren't true?** Was there any "room for artistic interpretation" when creating this series, or, did the producers try to be as accurate as possible all throughout the season?